# Reactjs - Isotope - expand and collapse on click - but have ONLY one item at a time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jquery-isotope

I am working on an isotope application - and I want to smooth this application so that onclick an item expands -- but on clicking another item - it closes the last -- here is the code base - what is the best way of handling this. My problem at the moment is its possible to open up multiple cells at once - and I haven't worked out the logic to collapse non-active items.

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-sea-tnih7?file=/src/IsotopePopClickEl.js

IsotopePopClickEl.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
//import Rating from '@material-ui/lab/Rating';

//import parse from 'html-react-parser';

import "./IsotopePopClickEl.css";

class IsotopePopClickEl extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = { expanded: false };
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  expand() {
    this.setState({
      expanded: true
    });
  }

  collapse(event) {
    this.setState({
      expanded: false
    });
  }

  onClick() {
    if (this.state.expanded) {
      this.collapse();
    } else {
      this.expand();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className={
          "isotope-pop-click " +
          (this.state.expanded ? "is-expanded" : "is-collapsed")
        }
        onClick={this.onClick}
      >
        <div className="frontFace">
          <Grid container spacing={0}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
              <div className="image-wrapper">
                <img
                  className="image-item"
                  src={this.props.item.image}
                  alt=""
                />
              </div>
              <h3>{this.props.item.label}</h3>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>

        <div className="backFace">
          <Grid container spacing={0}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={5}>
              <div className="image-wrapper">
                <img
                  className="image-item"
                  src={this.props.item.image}
                  alt=""
                />
              </div>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={7}>
              <h3>{this.props.item.label}</h3>
              <div>
                <p>some body text text text text</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
                  Read more
                </Button>
              </div>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default IsotopePopClickEl;
```

I wasn't sure what is the easier way to handle this -- if its a case of pushing back an active item record into the parent shell IsotopeWrapper - and if a new click is picked up to close all other IsotopePopClickEl's --

Comment: For what it's worth, what you're describing is typically called an "accordion"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to make bunch of changed to your codesandbox as there are few issues with existing code. Updated and working [codesandbox can be found here](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-dirac-ydtjh).

Let's go through the changes I made:

1. Notify parent/container as soon as item is clicked so that parent can update state of other items. To do that, I removed `state` from `IsotopePopClickEl` and moved it to `IsotopeWrapper` where wrapper would set `selected` property on each item to indicate if it is selected (or you can call it expanded!) or not.

```
class IsotopePopClickEl extends Component {
  ...
  onClick() {
    this.props.onClick();
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className={
          "isotope-pop-click " +
          (this.props.item.selected ? "is-expanded" : "is-collapsed")
        }
        onClick={this.onClick}
      >
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

2. Update state (selected) of each item so that `IsotopePopClickEl` can determine which item to expand to:

```
class IsotopeWrapper extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      resultsList: [
        // items in the list
      ]
    };
  }

  onClick(item) {
    const newList = this.state.resultsList.map((i) => {
      i.selected = i === item;
      return i;
    });
    this.setState({
      resultsList: newList
    });
  }

  render() {
    let items = [
      {
        buildEntity: () => ( // <- converted entity prop to method
          <IsotopePopClickEl
            item={this.state.resultsList[0]} // <- use item from the state
            onClick={() => this.onClick(this.state.resultsList[0])} // <- attach click handler
          />
        ),
        ...
      }
    ...
  }
}
```

3. Finally, not sure if you noticed but I replaced `entity` property on each item in `IsotopeWrapper` class with `buildEntity` function as using property would cache view after creating it for the first time and will not update after wards on new state. Update `IsotopeHandler` to call `buildEntity`.

```
<div className="grid-item-wrapper">{item.buildEntity()}</div>
```

That's all!

Comment: you got a sandbox for it -- I would keep the state still in the isotopepopclick - but update it as a prop -- and have a state inside the wrapper

Comment: Not sure it it will work. May be you can update codesandbox and share?

Comment: the issue is -- that the list here -- could push to use a different entity -- so it may not be an isotopePopClick -- I mean I think the parent shell could retain an array of active/non active states - and then on listening to a click - close all children, then open the child requested. So that's why I feel the isotopePopClick - should retain its state - active/non active -- but also be forced to close or open via the parent shell

Comment: Well, do you see this becoming out of sync? Also, why would you duplicate something in child component if parent shell is already providing that data?

Comment: well if you click on the same item it should close again.

Comment: Sure, you can put that logic in parent: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-browser-8yr3k

Comment: that parent really - should be wrapped again - cause where the items are coming from - is from the top level -- it would be a page which contains the module -- so really need to carve it up to make it an IstopePopClickHandler - with the IsotopePopClickEl as its children

Comment: Sure, but that is not the case currently in the shared code, right? and to do that you will have to rewire shared codesandbox. Isotopwrapper is the top most component currently, right after App component.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-murdock-n1hqq - here is a new sandbox - I started on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222823/discussion-between-dipen-shah-and-the-old-county).

Comment: I did pretty much everything you listed here -- but with the entity -- I pushed the isotopeclickpopel - just as another child element - so it gets controlled at the state level itself -- so I just added a new param -- called type - to do a conditon here if it should be an isoclickel or just a given markup

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it well for the way you mentioned where you want to be able to open multiple items at the same time. But as you want only to open each time, you should move the state to the parent component and that state should be an identifier of the element that is currently opened by, i.e, the id of the element.

So you should end up with something like:

```
this.state = { expanded: "itemId" }
```

Your onclick method will be something like:

```
onClick(e) {
  this.setState({ expanded: e.target.id }) // use the identifier that you want
}
```

And in each `IsotopePopClickEl` you just check if the `id` (or whatever) of the element is the same as `this.state.expanded` and if true, you append the class. This can be done if you map some items to that `IsotopePopClickEl` component or if you just copy/paste them to the same parent component (first one is a better approach obviously).

In that first approach you should pass new props to `IsotopePopClickEl` to check that parent's state of which item is `expanded`

Comment: you able to modify the sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-sea-tnih7?file=/src/IsotopePopClickEl.js  --- wouldn't you want to keep the logic separated to toggle the class in each child -- really I would say to push data into the parent to notify the parent which child is active, and if this changes - close other children with a prop change. --- which in the child the state is changed by the prop change